# Is BLL absolutely necessary?

Tags: bll

I'm new to the .Net world. I'm creating a website. It has DAL & Presentation Layer. As I mentioned earlier I'm a novice & I'm not sure how to create a BLL. So I was wondering if my current approach is fine? Will it cause any problems? Its a simple application which queries the SQL Server Database, Selects & Updates the Tables. Please help me understand this better

Comment: **1)** We have no clue what you are talking about when you say, "as I mentioned earlier"  **2)** We have no idea what your "current approach" is.  **3)** Your description of your "simple application" covers almost every web app under the sun, and is therefore not descriptive.  **4)** Therefore, this question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You really should have more attention to the tags. Please before posting another question here on StackOverflow, read the http://StackOverflow.com/FAQ, http://WhatHaveYouTried.Com and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548 thanks!*

Look up [CSLA](http://www.lhotka.net/) for a good example of what a good BLL is and does...

I suggest you don't bind your Presentation layer (ie user controls) to your DAL directly instead make an "Object Model" - ideally a nice, encapsulated, polymorphic, abstract API - sometimes referred to as a Domain Specific Language (ie DSL) that ties your DAL to any (client-side, mobile, etc) GUI through binding. Trust me, this will make writing tests much simpler.

That's a summary of the premise behind a BLL with reference to your example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helps. Sorry about the way I asked the question